# Item drawn in Custom view onDraw() keeps disappearing

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw

I'm drawing 3 things in my custom view in the onDraw() method: a vector drawable, a simple line and a triangle (made from 4 Points and a Path). This custom view is displayed in a tab.

If I swipe to go to another tab I see that the system calls onDraw(). When I return to the tab holding my custom view the vector drawable and simple line are still visible but the triangle has disappeared. If I now swipe to another tab, onDraw() runs again and back in the tab with the custom view, all items (including the triangle) are now visible. This disappearing/appearing continues to happen as I swipe back and forth. Why is my triangle disappearing?

**UPDATE 1 (hacky fix):**
I've tried experimenting and notice that when I move my triangle Path object creation out of my init() method and put it directly in the onDraw() method - then all works well, nothing disappears. But, I now get the 'Avoid object allocations during draw' warning as I'm creating this object in onDraw();

**UPDATE 2 (better fix?):**
After more experimenting, it's definitely the Path causing this problem. Another solution to this - which doesn't incur the 'Avoid object allocations during draw' warning is: keep Path creation in init() and remove the line of code 'myPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD)'. It solves my problem, but I've no idea why.

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Co-ordinates
        int width = getWidth();
        int halfWidth = width/2;
        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;
        int centreX = left + halfWidth;
        int centreY = top + halfWidth;
        int baseSize = Math.round((float)(halfWidth * 0.05));

        // Vector drawable - always draws fine!
        myVectorDrawable.setBounds(left, top, left + width, top + width);
        myVectorDrawable.draw(canvas);         

        // Simple line - always draws fine! 
        canvas.drawLine(left, top, 20, 20, paint);

        // Triangle - sometimes visible, sometimes disappears!
        Point myTriangleBottomMiddle = new Point(centreX, centreY);
        Point myTriangleBottomLeft = new Point(centreX, centreY + baseSize);
        Point myTriangleBottomRight = new Point(centreX, centreY - baseSize);
        Point myTriangleTopMiddle = new Point(centreX + halfWidth, centreY);
        myPath.moveTo(myTriangleBottomMiddle.x, myTriangleBottomMiddle.y);
        myPath.lineTo(myTriangleBottomLeft.x, mTriangleBottomLeft.y);
        myPath.lineTo(myTriangleTopMiddle.x, myTriangleTopMiddle.y);
        myPath.lineTo(myTriangleBottomRight.x, myTriangleBottomRight.y);
        mPath.close();
        canvas.drawPath(myPath, myPaint);

   }
```

Below the code where I set up stuff so as not to burden the onDraw() method.

```
private void init() {

    // Vector drawable
    myVectorDrawable = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_dial);

    // Triangle path - ** THIS BEING HERE SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM **
    myPath = new Path();
    myPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    // Triangle Paint
    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.black));
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    // Simple line paint
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the values of centreX and centreY are set elsewhere in your code, could they have incorrect values which cause the triangle to have different coordinates? maybe all 0s which would explain it being invisible

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for your post. I left the centreX/Y out to keep my code clear, but I've posted it back in above. They are based upon the width of the custom view - which doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to reset() on the path.

```
    // Triangle - sometimes visible, sometimes disappears!
    Point myTriangleBottomMiddle = new Point(centreX, centreY);
    Point myTriangleBottomLeft = new Point(centreX, centreY + baseSize);
    Point myTriangleBottomRight = new Point(centreX, centreY - baseSize);
    Point myTriangleTopMiddle = new Point(centreX + halfWidth, centreY);
    myPath.reset();
    myPath.moveTo(myTriangleBottomMiddle.x, myTriangleBottomMiddle.y);
    myPath.lineTo(myTriangleBottomLeft.x, mTriangleBottomLeft.y);
    myPath.lineTo(myTriangleTopMiddle.x, myTriangleTopMiddle.y);
    myPath.lineTo(myTriangleBottomRight.x, myTriangleBottomRight.y);
    mPath.close();
    canvas.drawPath(myPath, myPaint);
```

Also, I would recommend putting the vector drawable into a separate view so it's not redrawn everytime you need to animate the triangle (assuming this is going to be an animated guage dial).

Comment: Thanks Chris. You are correct, creating the Path object in onDraw() does solve it - but it means I'm getting the 'Avoid allocating objects in draw' warning still which isn't great.

Comment: See my Update #2 above. Another solution - but I don't know why?

Comment: Alternatively, you can call 
    myPath.reset();

Comment: Nice one! Doing myPath.reset() fixes it !

Comment: If you add that as a separate answer I can tick it.

Comment: So, I added myPath.reset() as the last line of code in my onDraw() method - when everything has finished drawing.